# I am having issues with parsing a variable from an SQL into another SQL statement with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){

//Connecting to the database

include('includes/connection.php');





// Creating variables to Post selected input item into database
$meeting_type = explode('|', $_POST['meeting_type']);
$date_picker = $_POST['date_picker'];

//$query = "SELECT * FROM meeting_tb WHERE meeting_type = '$meeting_type[1]'";
$query = "SELECT meeting_id, meeting_type, date FROM meeting_tb WHERE date in (select Max(date) as mindate from meeting_tb where meeting_type = '$meeting_type[1]')";



    $query_result = mysqli_query($db_con, $query) or die("error retrieving data");

    $row_meeting = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) or die("Not able to retrieve information");



$query_item = "SELECT join_tb.item_id, item_name, item_description FROM join_tb INNER JOIN meeting_item_tb ON join_tb.item_id = meeting_item_tb.item_id WHERE join_tb.meeting_id = '$row_meeting[meeting_id]'";

$result = mysqli_query($db_con, $query_item) or die("error retrieving data");

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr> <th>ITEM ID</th> <th>ITEM NAME</th>  <th>ITEM DESCRIPTION</th> </tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row['item_id'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['item_name'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['item_description'];
echo "</td></tr>";

}

echo "</table>";


}

//End of IF statement


?>
```

The Issue involves the use of `$row_meeting[meeting_id]` in the second select statement. If I put a numeric value in place of `$row_meeting[meeting_id]`, the select statement works and it displays an output on the browser. But if I use `$row_meeting[meeting_id]` in the second select statement, it does not get the data from the database

Comment: print_r($row_meeting).

Comment: sorry i dont understand this. I need to pull out information from the db using that query and it is not displaying on the web page bcos of the $row_meeting[meeting_id]. I think there is an issue somewhere.

Comment: ok echo $row_meeting[meeting_id];

Comment: i echo $row_meeting["meeting_id"]; and it gave me the meeting_id value of "2".

Comment: $query_item = "SELECT join_tb.item_id, item_name, item_description FROM join_tb INNER JOIN meeting_item_tb ON join_tb.item_id = meeting_item_tb.item_id WHERE join_tb.meeting_id = '".$row_meeting['meeting_id']."'";    echo $query_item ;

Comment: i have done that and i got = '2'. hmmmm...I guess there is something wrong somewhere.

Comment: if u have phpmyadmin execute query there and check it

Comment: i just did that. the query is valid, it displays the necessary item_id, item_name and item_description using a meeting_id value of '1'

Comment: I have gotten it. Thanks so much. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

By putting single inverted commas around `$row_meeting[meeting_id]`, you are converting the number to a string when parsing it to SQL. To avoid parsing it to as string you can simply remove the single inverted commas. So your select statement will look like:

```
$query_item = "SELECT join_tb.item_id, item_name, item_description FROM join_tb INNER JOIN meeting_item_tb ON join_tb.item_id = meeting_item_tb.item_id WHERE join_tb.meeting_id = $row_meeting['meeting_id']";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just did what you prescribed. But the issue is that it is not pulling those values from the database after running the query based on $row_meeting[meeting_id]. It just leaves the display table on the web page blank with Item ID, Item_name, Item_description

Comment: Since its an associative array you need to put the column names in inverted commas too. Something that i missed earlier

Comment: I did that and got this error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in ......

Comment: Is that error on the same line as your query? try echoing $row_meeting["meeting_id"]; - as Sugumar suggested and let us know what yo uget

Comment: i echo $row_meeting["meeting_id"]; and it gave me the meeting_id value of "2"

Comment: I'm assuming meeting_id is a INT, when you fetch the data from the database it converts everything to string. try this
$meetingId = intval($row_meeting['meeting_id'];
Then in your query: "joint_tb.meeting_id = $meetingId;"

Comment: You are right, it is an integer. I just tried using what you suggested and it still does not pull out the values from the database. I do not know why it does this. If i use the value from the database i.e. using meeting_id as '1' it pulls data from the database.

Comment: Try doing a var_dump($row); as the first line of your while loop.

Then see what you get when you use 1 and the variable $meetingId

Comment: when i used '1': It showed: array (size=3)
  'item_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'item_name' => string 'The educational sector budget' (length=29)
  'item_description' => string 'This gives a view on the type of ' (length=33)

1The educational sector budgetThis gives a view on the type of

array (size=3)
  'item_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'item_name' => string 'The financial budget' (length=20)
  'item_description' => string 'This is a budget that summaries the amount of ' (length=46)

2The financial budgetThis is a budget that summaries the amount of

Comment: when i used meetingId, nothing was posted. and no error showed. It was like it refreshed the page.

Comment: can you confirm that you got something from $row_meeting to begin with. If you got nothing and there is no error, it suggests to me that it might be empty.

Comment: Man, thanks so much. That last sentence gave me an idea. The issue was from my database. I was actually pulling out empty rows. that was a stupid error by me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your second query

```
$query_item = "SELECT join_tb.item_id, item_name, item_description FROM join_tb INNER JOIN meeting_item_tb ON join_tb.item_id = meeting_item_tb.item_id WHERE join_tb.meeting_id = ".$row_meeting[meeting_id].";";
```

It is possible because of the single quoted around the variable.

Comment: When i use ".$row_meeting[meeting_id].";". It does not pull the required info from the database,but says: the Use of undefined constant meeting_id - assumed 'meeting_id'